# Tableau Server Extracts issue

Tags: tableau-api

A developer had created dashboard and successfully published to tableau server for auto refresh extract every day, Developer had data and DB access at that time. 
Now the same developer's access for DB is removed, is it possible to get fresh data to reports everyday? will the extract have new data everyday ?

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you update the database credentials published with the data source to be something that the database accepts

You typically want some sort of service account for this purpose - so that the published dashboards still work when the original publisher leaves

Comment: We do have service account called Tableau prod server environment, still we have issue with refreshing the extracts - as no data is being refreshed.

Comment: //1 
I am tableau developer, I have created workbook using tableau desktop  which contains multiple dashboards, data sources, while creating workbook I have used Extracts.
Now I have signed in to shared tableau server of my company called "Production" and published my workbook, production does have data base access. 
But I am having problem in refreshing extracts. Extracts are not getting refreshed- tried most of possible ways like Relogin to prod server, checking database connection, checking prod server connections. Can anyone please suggest solution for this?

Comment: //2 Note: I do not have my separate credentials for tableau prod server environment, I signin in to Tableau prod sever environment with shared Tableau prod server credentials.
but workbook that is created is in my tableau desktop having my own credentials. 
Second thing when I publish same workbook in Tableau server - (developer environment -belongs to our project, where I have access and has linked with data base as well, the workbook is properly published with no issue with extracts auto refreshed.
Or share correct steps to publish dashboard with extract in to prod server environment.

Comment: I don't mean a service account that the Tableau server executes under. I mean you should have an account that your database server recognizes that you use for published dashboards. Then the database credentials associated with the published data source connection should use that account. That's called embedded credentials.

Comment: There are a few other options. Challenge each user to supply a database user name and password - the opposite of embedding your database credentials. OR with some data sources you use an impersonation feature to "poss through" the user identity from Tableau Server to the database - via Kerberos in some cases.